# Swift 4 : error: extraneous argument label

Tags: swift, string, swift4

I am new to Swift. Trying some coding in Swift 4 beta version.

Here is what I am trying:

```
var testString = "Testing the string"
```

this works fine:

```
testString.insert("!", at: testString.endIndex)
```

but this won't work:

```
testString.insert(contentsOf: " there", at: testString.index(before: testString.endIndex))
```

> Extraneous argument label `contentsOf:` in call.

Swift 4 is supposed to support this right?
Can anyone tell me whats the problem here?

Comment: Compiles fine for me in Swift 4 (version that ships w/ Xcode 9 beta 2)

Comment: It works at IBM Swift Sandbox: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5956314a3ff16275477b6802

Answer (score 1):

I run your code in Swift 3 and got same error. You may check your Swift version with this command

```
swift -version
```

Comment: I think he is running **Swift 4** ;)

Comment: I am trying this in Swift 4 language in playground. Getting the same error again.